# osm2po way tag resolver: how to use allow/deny for complex selection

Tags: osm2po

How to combine allow / deny in osm2po config file for complex selection?

As an example, I would like to include in my finalmask (car) all [highway=service] except the ones that DO NOT have the tag [surface=asphalt].
I would like to use this asphalt restriction only for highway=service but not for other types of highways. What should I write in my osm2po config file to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 5.2.72 the declaration format has changed.
So I recommend to download the latest version (current is 5.2.84, link is on the download tab)
There are some comments regarding this in the osm2po.config.

Example (**new format**): To allow roads and service ways set

```
wtr.finalMask=road,service
```

If not all service ways are allowed, set sth. like this here:

```
wtr.flagList=road,service,asphalt
wtr.finalMask=road,service|asphalt
wtr.allow.surface.asphalt=asphalt
```

Another approach is to think the whole matter more abstract.
I haven't tested it yet, but this should work as well:
(Tricky part: service has no flags by default)

```
wtr.flagList=car
wtr.finalMask=car
wtr.tag.highway.service = 1,51,5
wtr.tag.highway.motorway = 1,11,120,car
wtr.allow.surface.asphalt=car
```

If you prefer the technical and non-verbose version, here it is:

```
wtr.finalMask=0x1
wtr.tag.highway.service = 1,51,5
wtr.tag.highway.motorway = 1,11,120,0x1
wtr.allow.surface.asphalt=0x1
```

Comment: I tested with success the first approach.